# After end of result set error (probably with string)

Tags: mysql

I'm just wondering how to get rid of this error:

```
try {
    int ppointd;
    String nazwa;
    int smr;
    int zab;
    PreparedStatement pktUpdate = Main.c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `staty` ORDER BY `pkt` DESC LIMIT 10");
    ResultSet rs1 = pktUpdate.executeQuery();
    for(int i = 1; i<11; i++) {
        rs1.next();
        nazwa = rs1.getString("Nazwa");
        zab = rs1.getInt("zab");
        smr = rs1.getInt("smr");
        ppointd = rs1.getInt("pkt");
        p.sendMessage("§a"+i+". §e" + nazwa + " §b- §6PKT: §7[§4" + ppointd+ "§7] §6ZAB: §7[§4"+zab+"§7] §6SMR: §7[§4"+smr+"§7]");
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I made some digging and I know it's about this `String`, but I have no clue how to skip this and have same output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You call `rs1.next()` in a loop from 1 to 10, but what if your SELECT query returns fewer than 10 rows?

When you call `rs1.next()` you need to test if that method returns false, and if so, break out of the loop.

For example, it's more common to code it the following way instead of using a for loop:

```
while (rs1.next()) {
    . . .
}
```

That way the loop automatically stops when there are no more rows.